# VS2012 Add-In for Qt4 support doesn't work?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

Apparently the VS Add-In for Qt4 support (version 1.1.11) does not install in VS2012 Premium.  This looks like a deal breaker in that anyone continuing the use of 4.8.4 libraries in Qt projects can not develop in VS2012.  The add-in DID in fact work in VS2010 as well as the version which supprts Qt5 (1.2.2) also co-existed within VS2010

Hopefully someone has a fix.

Comment: See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19013697/1329652).

Comment: I put back the TIA as I feel it to be appropriate.  Tell me where I'm wrong to do that.

Comment: It's redundant. The question is a question, not a personal letter. We're sure you're grateful, but it's noise. If you weren't grateful you wouldn't say so anyway, so what's the point. See e.g. [this answer on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/232821).

Comment: I understand.  I wasn't being flippant.  I didn't know there was such strict protocol.  Sorry for the 10 character noise offense.