# How to generate a Visual Studio project file when I build my qmake project?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qmake

I like to do most development using Qt Creator, and the builds are driven with qmake and jom. I occasionally want to use Visual Studio for debugging. I'd like to know what magic to put into the `.pro` file to automatically generate a Visual Studio project file during the project build, every time the `.pro` file changes.

Comment: In-case you weren't aware of it, there's the Qt Visual Studio Add-in, which opens up the Qt .pro file, without adding anything extra: http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other

Comment: @Merlin069: That's fine if you can use the add-in. The Qt 4 and Qt 5 add-ins can't coexist AFAIK, and there's no Qt 4 plugin for VS2012. In my case, I need support for Qt 4 and Qt 5 on VS2012.

Comment: Fair enough, that wasn't mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your qmake project set up so that it automatically generates a Visual Studio project file on every build.

The below assumes that the base name of the `.pro` file is the same as the `TARGET`. Say, if you have `TARGET = myapp`, you must have it in `myapp.pro`. Simply add the lines below to your .pro file.

There is a side effect: every change to the `.pro` file forces re-linking of the executable.

The script below supports generating your Visual Studio project no matter what your target mkspec is. Thus it can be generated whether you build on Windows or Unix, and whether you build for Visual Studio on Windows, or using some other compiler

```
win32-msvc* {
    # Works when you build for Visual Studio already
    vsproj.spec = $$basename(QMAKESPEC)
} else {
    # Works when you're not building for Visual Studio (say, using mingw)
    # The configuration you want to build the VS project for (win32-msvc[2005|2008|2010|2012])
    vsproj.spec = win32-msvc2008
}
# Sets the project file name appropriately to selected Visual Studio version.
contains(vsproj.spec, win32-msvc201): vsproj.target = $${TARGET}.vcxproj
else: vsproj.target = $${TARGET}.vcproj
# The qmake command to make the Visual Studio project file
vsproj.commands = qmake -tp vc $${_PRO_FILE_} -spec $${vsproj.spec}
# The VS project depends on the .pro file
vsproj.depends = $${_PRO_FILE_}
# Set the above as a target in the makefile.
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += vsproj
# Make the main target (the executable/library) depend on it,
# so that it gets built.
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $${vsproj.target}
```